# What is this insect found in a shower?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I hope the picture is clear enough, I've found a worm like insect like the one below a little while ago in my shower, and today I found another one. I've never seen something like this. I would say it is slightly bigger than a centimeter.

**Location: Netherlands**
[image]
Why do they come in my shower ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a species of [**silverfish**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepismatidae) such as *[Ctenolepisma longicaudata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctenolepisma_longicaudata)* or *[Lepisma saccharina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverfish)* for examples (thanks @RHA for correction in comments).

Silvefish are well known very resistant pest typically found in washrooms and sometimes in kitchens. They are not directly dangerous but can cause property damage. [Here is a webpage](https://www.creaturecontrol.net/insect-pest-control/silverfish/) giving advice on how to get rid of them

[image]

Comment: It might be a silverfish or a paperfish. And getting rid of them is, at least in the Dutch climate, virtually impossible. I speak from expierence here. Unless maybe, if you convince all your neighbours to do the same...

Comment: What is a paperfish? I could not find a wikipedia entry for paperfish except for a fish species. Yes, silverfish are really resistant and it can be really hard to get rid of them esp. in apartment building.

Comment: Sorry. It is Ctenolepisma longicaudata, called gray silverfish in English. Paperfish is my bad translation of the Dutch 'papiervisje'. It eats books...